# How to pass variables in curl?

Tags: curl

The goal is to create an account at example.com. We need an **alphanumeric name**, which we got.

**What we have:**

```
$name="egon111"
$pw="notegon"

curl -s -X POST -d 'username="'"$name"'"&password="'"$pw"'"' https://example.com/create
```

**We need normally the following curl command:**

```
curl -s -X POST -d "username=egon111&password=notegon" https://example.com/create
```

What's wrong with the syntax? In my opinion we currently send as name `$name` and as password `$pw` exactly, not the variable itself, which is totally wrong.
We get the following error:

```
Select a username that is alphanumeric.
```

Greetz,
Klara

*I am new at stackoverflow. Feel free to comment so that I can improve myself.*

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Excellent first question. :-) It would be helpful if you mentioned what shell you're using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your assignment is incorrect, as @sideshowbarker noted. In the shell, unlike Perl or PHP or global variables in Ruby, you don't use the `$` on variables when assigning them, but only when referencing them:

```
name="egon111"
pw="notegon"
```

But that still leaves the problem of the literal quotation marks in the `curl` command. Query string parameters (and their `POST`ed equivalents in the request body) should not be quoted. (The quotation marks in the above assignment are shell syntax that don't get stored in the variables; you could leave them off entirely in this case since the values you're assigning don't contain any whitespace, but they're harmless.)

But query string/POST body parameters are not shell parameters. Your `curl` command:

```
curl -s -X POST -d 'username="'"$name"'"&password="'"$pw"'"' https://example.com/create
```

gets expanded by the shell to the equivalent of this:

```
'curl' '-s' '-X' 'POST' '-d' 'username="egon111"&password="notegon"' \ 
  'https://example.com/create'
```

Note the literal `"` around the values of both `username` and `password`. Those are interpreted by the web server as part of those parameter values, not quoting syntax. And since quotation marks are not alphanumeric, you get the error message you posted.

You can just remove the extra quotes, and it should work fine:

```
curl -s -X POST -d 'username='"$name"'&password='"$pw" https://example.com/create
```

But that's noisier than it needs to be. You don't need to put the `username=` and `&password=` in single quotes, since there's nothing there that might be expanded. You need to quote the `&`, but double quotes work fine for that. So you can simply do this instead:

```
curl -s -X POST -d "username=$name&password=$pw" https://example.com/create
```

Comment: curl -s -X POST -d 'username='"$name"'&password='"$pw" https://example.com/create - This did the job! Thx alot ;)

Comment: I'm also a big fan of bash's `printf '%q'`. In this case, `curl -s -X POST -d "$(printf 'username=%q&password=%q' "$name" "$pw")" https://example.com/create` .. though the OP hasn't indicated that she's using bash.

Comment: @ghoti - `printf %q` also works in ksh and zsh, FWIW.